# How do I create additional fields in module.install?

Tags: nodes, entities

I am creating a module in the ".install" file, using the following code:

```
// if not exists, create new content type
if (!node_get_types('type', 'houses')) {
  $info = array(
    'type' => 'houses',
    'name' => t('Houses'),
    'module' => 'node',
    'description' => t('Manager Houses'),
    'locked' => FALSE,
    'custom' => TRUE,
  );
  $info = _node_type_set_defaults($info);
  node_type_save((object)$info);
}
```

It creates a new content type, but how do I create additional fields (e.g. text, nodereference)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of creating the node type and fields by hand in code, you should use the [features](http://drupal.org/project/features) module which does the same thing, but has support for a bunch of other things as well, like reverting changes made to what is saved in code.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [programmatically created cck fields](http://drupal.org/node/793072).  Also see [Creating a Compound Field Module for CCK in Drupal 6.x](http://www.poplarware.com/articles/cck_field_module) and [Programmatically add CCK field to content type](http://drupal.org/node/702156).